# Stack using priority Queue in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have come up with the below code but somehow its not working as expected.  What could be the reason of this. Idea is to make a pair of count and item to be pushed to the priority queue and then just pop.But how to implement this in python3?

```
import heapq

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dict ={}
        self.cnt = 0
        self.hq = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.heappush(hq, {self.cnt:item})

    def pop(self):
        self.cnt -= 1
        return self.heappop(hq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Stack()
    s.push(10)
    s.push(20)
    s.push(30)
    print(s.pop())
```

I am receiving the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shrivatsa/Documents/E/Learning-Path/Python/Algorithms and Datastructure/stackpriorityqueue.py", line 19, in <module>
    s.push(10)
  File "/home/shrivatsa/Documents/E/Learning-Path/Python/Algorithms and Datastructure/stackpriorityqueue.py", line 11, in push
    self.heappush(hq, {self.cnt:item})
AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'heappush'
```

Comment: *"somehow its not working as expected"* - how did you expect it to work? How does it work instead? Give  a [mcve].

Comment: the above code should work like a stack. i.e when I print(s.pop()) it should output me 30.

Comment: ...and what happens instead? [Edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: I am getting the error as :  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shrivatsa/Documents/E/Learning-Path/Python/Algorithms and Datastructure/stackpriorityqueue.py", line 19, in <module>
    s.push(10)
  File "/home/shrivatsa/Documents/E/Learning-Path/Python/Algorithms and Datastructure/stackpriorityqueue.py", line 11, in push
    self.heappush(hq, {self.cnt:item})
AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'heappush'

Comment: **Again**, [edit] the question. That's unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `self` keyword is used to reference the **object**, this way we can specify we're referring to attributes or methods **defined within the class**. `heappush` and `heappop` are not defined in the Stack class but in the `heapq` library so you should call them `heapq.heappush` and `heapq.heappop` instead.

Another issue to take into account is that dictionaries do not have an ordering defined, and thus they can't be pushed into a heap. If you want to save these pairs you should use tuples instead.

Example:

```
import heapq

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.hq = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.cnt += 1
        heapq.heappush(self.hq, (self.cnt, item))

    def pop(self):
        self.cnt -= 1
        return heapq.heappop(self.hq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Stack()
    s.push(10)
    s.push(20)
    s.push(30)
    print(s.pop())
```

Comment: But using this I am getting output as 10 instead of 30. For the stack it should have output 30.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the `heapq` library? maybe you could use just the builtin `pop` method of the lists ( this is replacing `heapq.heappush(self.hq, (self.cnt, item))` for `self.hq.append((self.cnt, item))` and `heapq.heappop(self.hq)` for `self.hq.pop()` )

Comment: The reason is question itself is asking to use the priority Queue build the stack..

Comment: The `heapq` library provides heap queues, the documentation of `heapq.heappop` states it "Pop and return the smallest item from the heap". Maybe what you're looking for is the `PriorityQueue` from the `queue` library.

Answer (score 0):

`heappush` and `heappop` are functions in the `heapq` library. When you write `self.heappush(...)`, for example, you're saying "call a function in this class called `heappush`, using the data from this instance)". But your class `Stack` doesn't have a function called `heappush`, hence the error.

To call the functions from the `heapq` library, use `heapq.heappush(...)` and `heapq.heappop(...)` instead.